# Tests PASS outside Vagrant, FAIL inside Vagrant

Tags: phantomjs, vagrant, casperjs

I'm running a CasperJS script on a Mac and inside a Vagrant box. **Tests succeed outside of Vagrant but not inside of it. Why?**

For reference, I've put the test results at the bottom of this post.

#### Versions (same in and out of Vagrant)

- casper: 1.1.0-beta3
- phantom: 1.9.7
- OSX: 10.9.4
- vagrant: 1.3.5

If anything more is needed to debug, please let me know, I'll add :-)

#### The test command

This is what I'm using in the console to run the tests.

```
casperjs test price_filter.js
```

#### The test script

This should work for you as well since `www3.smatch.com` is publicly accessible. Basically, the script goes to 'Lady Accessoires' section, finds Products in the DOM and gets their price. Then it checks that at least one product has a high price and after applying a price filter checks that there are no more high priced products.

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.test.begin(
    'max price filter',
    function suite(test) {
        casper.start('http://www3.smatch.com/');

        casper.then(function() {
            this.mouseEvent('mouseover', '.header a[title="Damenmode"]');
        });

        casper.thenClick(x('//*[text()="Accessoires"]'));

        casper.then(function() {
            var elements = this.evaluate(function() {
                var elements = __utils__.findAll('.category-content .products[data-result] .price');

                return elements.map(function(el) {
                    return el.textContent.trim();
                });
            });

            var haveExpensive = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
            {
                if (elements[i].match(/^[0-9]{2,},[0-9][0-9]/))
                {
                    haveExpensive = true;
                }
                else if (!elements[i].match(/^[0-9]+,[0-9][0-9]/))
                {
                    throw new Error('invalid price');
                }
            }

            if (!haveExpensive)
                throw new Error('no expensive products');

            test.assert(elements.length > 0, 'Before filter, we have expensive products');
        });

        casper.then(function() {
            this.fillSelectors('#price-filter-form', {
                'input[name="max"]': '7'
            });
        });

        casper.thenClick('#price-filter-submit');

        casper.then(function() {
            var elements = this.evaluate(function() {
                var elements = __utils__.findAll('.category-content .products[data-result] .price');

                return elements.map(function(el) {
                    return el.textContent.trim();
                });
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
            {
                if ( ! elements[i].match(/^[0-7],[0-9][0-9]/))
                    throw new Error(elements[i]);
            }

            test.assert(elements.length > 0, 'After filter, we have cheap products');
        });

        casper.run(function () {
            test.done();
        });
    }
);
```

#### Test results

**Outside Vagrant**

```
Test file: price_filter.js
# max price filter
PASS Before filter, we have expensive products
PASS After filter, we have cheap products
PASS 2 tests executed in 1.202s, 2 passed, 0 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.
```

**Inside Vagrant**

```
Test file: critical/price_filter.js
# max price filter
PASS Before filter, we have expensive products
FAIL Error: 89,90

                    * €
#    type: uncaughtError
#    file: critical/price_filter.js:62
#    error: 89,90

                    * €
#           Error: 89,90
#
#                               * €
#               at critical/price_filter.js:62
#               at runStep (/usr/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1553)
#               at checkStep (/usr/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:399)
#    stack: not provided
FAIL 2 tests executed in 21.873s, 1 passed, 1 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.

Details for the 1 failed test:

In critical/price_filter.js:62
  max price filter
    uncaughtError: Error: 89,90

                    * €
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really strange, but it seems to be solvable by adding an empty step behind the click:

```
casper.thenClick('#price-filter-submit');
casper.then(function(){});
```

or

```
casper.thenClick('#price-filter-submit');
casper.wait(1); // 1 msec
```

I cannot offer any insight why that might be. Maybe it is a casperjs bug.

Comment: Could it be the time the event delegation system takes to understand that there is a click to handle? The form is submitted this way. Anyways, thanks :)

Comment: It might be that the form submission is somehow triggered not entirely synchronous and this way casper doesn't see the `page.navigation.requested` event fast enough, so that it just continues executing without waiting for the new page to load. The empty step might catch that slight asynchronous behavior.